# save and reload directory history

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I would like to save the last $cnt entries of the `Get-Location -Stack` when powershell exits, and then reload that history when powershell starts.
This does not work:

```
Register-EngineEvent PowerShell.Exiting {  
  Get-Location -Stack | Select -Last 5 | Export-CliXml $HistoryPath -Encoding UTF8  
} -SupportEvent
```

The .xml has no entries, even though "Get-Location -Stack" run at the command line shows several entries.
If I run the same command getting history and piping through the Export-CliXml cmdlet during the powershell session, it works as expected.
Similarly, exporting command history works as expected.
What am I doing wrong trying to export the directory history?

Comment: I extracted the functionality to save cmd history in to one function, and the functionality to save dir history into another function.  When I call those two functions from PowerShell.Exiting, everything seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you ever initialize `$HistoryPath` to a valid path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  $HistoryPath was initialized.